# Object starts spinning when applying linear impulse - iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, box2d

In my game I'm using Box2D to apply linear impulse to a circle object. When the impulse is applied to the object, it starts spinning clockwise but I can't get it to stop spinning.

Here is the code:

```
-(void) ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [self convertTouchToNodeSpace:touch];

    CGPoint vector = ccpSub(ccp(touchLocation.x,touchLocation.y), _ball.position);

    b2Vec2 forceVector(vector.x / 5, vector.y / 5);

    if ((vector.x <= 100) && (vector.y <= 100))
         _ballBody->ApplyLinearImpulse(forceVector, _ballBody->GetLocalCenter());
}
```

Hope someone could clarify the situation.

UPD:

```
// Create ball body and shape
    b2BodyDef ballBodyDef;
    ballBodyDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;
    ballBodyDef.position.Set(100/PTM_RATIO, 100/PTM_RATIO);
    ballBodyDef.userData = _ball;
    _ballBody = _world->CreateBody(&ballBodyDef);

    b2CircleShape circle;
    circle.m_radius = 26.0/PTM_RATIO;

    b2FixtureDef ballShapeDef;
    ballShapeDef.shape = &circle;
    ballShapeDef.density = 0.3f;
    ballShapeDef.friction = 0.2f;
    ballShapeDef.restitution = 0.4f;
    _ballBody->CreateFixture(&ballShapeDef);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `body->applyLinearImpulse(impulse, body->GetPosition())`

Comment: And what is the difference between this two lines:           
1) `_ballBody->ApplyLinearImpulse(forceVector, _ballBody->GetLocalCenter());`     
2) `body->applyLinearImpulse(impulse, body->GetPosition());`

Comment: Thanks Andrew!
Works great. Could you explain why was the object spinning?

Comment: Unless you apply impulse at the center of mass of the body it will spin. GetPosition() returns the reference frame of the body in the world, which is not always the center of mass. If you want to guarantee no spinning, use: body->ApplyLinearImpulse(impulse, body->GetWorldCenter())

Comment: iforce2d is right. the difference is that you are getting coords in local system of the body, but you need them in global system